# find minimal polynomial of $T(f) = f - 2f'$ , $T:P_2 (\mathbb{R}) \to P_2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, linear-transformations, minimal-polynomials

So for finding the characteristic polynomial, I used the base $\left\{1,x,x^2\right\}$ and found that its $(x-1)^3$,

but im not really sure how to find the minimal polynomial. to my understanding I need to put $x= ?$ and get that $(x-1)$ or $(x-1)^2$ or $(x-1)^3$ $= 0$, but what do I set $x$ to?
thanks in advance.

Im also unable to figure out how to find if its diagnosable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) that minimial polynomial divides characteristic polynomial.
Using $\{1,x,x^2\}$ basis, find matrix representation of $T$:
$$
T(1) = 1, \; T(x) = x - 2x' = x - 2, \; T(x^2) = x^2 - 2(x^2)' = x^2 - 4x\\
\mathbb{T} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & -2 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -4\\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
As $\det(\lambda \mathbb{I}-\mathbb{T}) = (\lambda-1)^3$, minimal polynomial can be either $\lambda -1$, $(\lambda -1)^2$ or $(\lambda -1)^3$. Obviously, $\mathbb{T} - \mathbb{I}$ is non-zero matrix, and neither is $(\mathbb{T} - \mathbb{I})^2$ (it has zeros everywhere except top right element. So, minimal polynomial is $(\lambda - 1)^3$.

Also, this matrix isn't diagonalizable:
$$(\mathbb{I}-\mathbb{T})f = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -4\\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}f = 0$$
has only 1-dimensional set of solutions.

Comment: so this is what I dont understand - is the minimal polynomial always the characteristic polynomial? since I use det(λI−T) to find the characteristic polynomial. I do understand that MP | CP, but why in this case its not (λ−1)^2 or λ−1 ? and on that note, how to I show it has only one set of solutions? Im pretty solid on the way to do it with Matrixs but not with polynomials

Comment: Since $P_2(\mathbb{R})$ is three-dimensional, you can think of polynomial $a + b x + c x^2$ as vector $(a, b, c)$, and represent given linear operator with matrix.

Comment: Thanks Vercassivelaunos, my bad, I’ll correct it